# willSet не выводит значение

Tags: ios, swift

Имеется следующий код структуры, которая должна запрашивать ширину, высоту и длину, а по итогу выводить объём, или уведомлять что объём не запрошен. На это всё дело я отвел `willSet`, который я как раз изучаю.

Что я делаю не так, почему у меня в консоли пусто и `willSet` не выводит никакой `print` из предложенных?

````
    
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
    let lenght: Int
    
    var volume: Bool {
        willSet {
            if newValue == true {
                let volumeNum = width * height * lenght
                print("Ваш объем \(volumeNum)")
            } else {
                print("Объём не запрошен")
            }
        }
    }
}

var car1 = Opel(width: 12, height: 21, lenght: 15, volume: true)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

willSet срабатывает после инициализации свойств. Попробуйте вот так:

```
var car1 = Opel(width: 12, height: 21, lenght: 15, volume: true)
car1.volume = true
```

И увидите, что willSet сработал.

Comment: Тогда правильнее ещё будет сделать volume опциональной вообще?
```var volume: Bool? {
        willSet {```

Тогда и в конечном итоге не надо будет вводить true или false.

Comment: Это на ваше усмотрение. Может быть, в начале вы хотите установить значение в false, а затем проверять его, например.